# Removing trailing newline from grep output

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

I'm looking for way to remove new line from grep output, I use

```
grep -oP "changed: \[([^]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'" /path/to/file
```

The output is like:

```
changed: [hostname1] =>
'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-03-04_20-37-18.log.1'
changed: [hostname2] =>
'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-02-04_13-42-42.log.0'
```

I need the key words changed and path will appear on same line like:

```
changed: [hostname1] => 'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-03-04_20-37-18.log.1'
changed: [hostname2] => 'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-02-04_13-42-42.log.0'`
```

I tried

```
grep -oP "changed: \[([^]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'" /path/to/file | tr -d '\n'
```

but it remove all new lines

Comment: And what's the input like? Are those `changed` and `path` on the same line in the input?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to join every two lines of the output of `grep` with spaces, pipe to:

```
paste -d ' ' - -
```

If you want to extract two parts of some line of the input and join them with space, use `pcregrep` instead of `grep -P` (where `-P` is to use PCRE in most `grep` implementations that support that non-standard `-P` option):

```
pcregrep --om-separator=' ' -o1 -o2 "(changed: \[[^]]+\] =>).*?('path': '[^']*')"
```

Or `perl`, (the `P`/`p` in all those):

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" while m{(changed: \[[^]]+\] =>).*?('"'path': '[^']*')}g"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` at first place.

```
$ awk "match(\$0, /changed: \[[^]]+\] =>|'path': '[^']*'/)\
  {
    buf=buf substr(\$0, RSTART, RLENGTH); c++
  }
  c==2{ print buf; c=buf=nul }" infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you show, you could use a tool to remove every second newline. For example, in `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 'chomp if $. % 2' file
changed: [hostname1] =>'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-03-04_20-37-18.log.1'
changed: [hostname2] =>'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-02-04_13-42-42.log.0'
```

You can add that to the end of your `grep`:

```
grep -oP "changed: \[([^]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'" /path/to/file | 
  perl -pe 'chomp if $. % 2'
```

Although if I were you, I would do as [Stéphane suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743037/22222) and just do the whole thing in perl to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/changed: \[[^]]+] =>|\047path\047: \047[^\047]*\047/) {
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), (++c % 2 ? OFS : ORS)
    }
' file
changed: [hostname1] => 'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-03-04_20-37-18.log.1'
changed: [hostname2] => 'path': '/confluence/app/logs/gc-2023-02-04_13-42-42.log.0'
```